# How could a third-party know the contents of an email I sent to someone?

Tags: email, privacy

Apparently, a third party knew the contents of an email I sent to someone within an hour after I sent it. The following possibilities come into mind:

1. The recipient forwarded the email to the third party. (I doubt this though as the email was sent to a business address on a non-business day.)
2. The third party has access to the recipient's account.
3. The third party has access to my email account.

Are there other possibilities I have failed to consider? How would I check those possibilities?

I was only able to check the possibility that the third party has access to my email account. Unfortunately the incident happened some time ago, and it seems to me there's no way to get your logged in IP addresses from Gmail after some time. So my only recourse is to change my current password to something stronger.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless the message or transmission was not encrypted, the e-mail could have been eavesdropped somewhen during transmission.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple additional ways:

- The message was not encrypted, and somebody captured it during transmission (as pointed out by Gumbo)
- The client is compromised and has some sort of malware that reads keystrokes, intercept emails, ...
- The recipient is compromised
- Any "mail relay" in between is compromised
- The recipient indeed did forward the mail, or the recipient address is an alias which delivers the mail to a number of users, who each might have forwarded the mail or be compromised.