# Is it possible to trick a CA into signing a certificate by intercepting on SSL domain validation email?

Tags: encryption, email, certificate-authority, man-in-the-middle

From my understanding domain validation certificate are verified by receiving an email on some special email addresses on the domain (e.g. postmaster@example.com, admin@example.com) or by sending on the designated email address on the domain name registration record (the information published on WHOIS).

Since [many emails servers from non major email service providers do not encrypt](http://www.google.com/transparencyreport/saferemail/) and only few email providers even supports STARTTLS. Therefore, it is possible to intercept emails sent to these vulnerable email providers (how hard would this be?).
Is domain validated certificate somewhat useless if the website's designated contact email address is hosted in less than secure email provider (e.g. self managed email servers in particular)?

What would prevent me from being issued a valid SSL certificate signed by a recognized CA for a domain I do not own by doing a passive/active MITM on an email service provider?

I'd assume that if you control the authoritative DNS, then you also control the Domain Validation by definition, so that's not realty a vulnerability. However, DNS caches is another matter, how could a CA make sure that its DNS entries comes from a legitimate source especially if the site owner don't make use of DNSSEC?

Comment: Just to be clear: you're considering a case where an attacker eavesdrops on (or impersonates) email between the domain's WHOIS contact email address and the CA, yes? Based on your comment below, it seems like the two parts to your question are: (1) Does the security of SSL reduce to the security of the email communication between the domain owner and the CA? (2) If so, how secure is that, exactly?

Comment: @apsillers: yes, that is correct, I've clarified the question a bit to that effect.

Comment: So the whole question is about *How realistic is it, that I can man-in-the-middle email traffic of a sysadmin?*

Comment: See also [How could a third-party know the contents of an email I sent to someone?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/52941/52333)

Comment: @LieRyan Does the linked topic answer your question? If yes, you can mark this one as duplicate. If not, please explain in more detail.

Comment: @sebix,apsillers: since both of you seem to be ignoring the first question (whether the security of CA are essentially the security of the email), I presume the answer to the first question is, yes, the security of the CA-based system is less than or equal to the ongoing security of the registrant's email system and not just the initial confirmation email?

Comment: Usually there is only one confirmation email prior to the issuance. I don't know of any ongoing checks like *If you don't confirm you are still the owner of this domain, the cert will be revoked*.

Comment: @sebix: I think it should be an ongoing security because the attacker can make a certificate signing request to a different CA to sign them a new certificate for the target domain, and if they can intercept the verification email, so that neither the real domain owner, the original CA, or even the attacker's CA would ever be the wiser that the website's encryption is now compromised. Is there anything else that would prevent the attacker from being improperly verified in such way?

Comment: I dealt with 3 CAs with Domain Validation and non of them had ongoing checks. This is also not their business which cert I use on my website. I can have more than one cert from different CAs and the CAs should not bother. I am - as administrator - responsible that an attacker can't hijack my email accounts, that's not the business of CAs.

Comment: @sebix: I don't mean the CA is doing ongoing check, but rather as long as the domain registration is valid, a CA may send their verification email to that registered email. This means that if your email is intercepted, the attacker can issue themselves a valid TLS certificate. It's not sufficient to ensure the secure delivery of email during your initial TLS verification, but rather you need to ensure continuous security of the email during the entire length of the domain registration.

Comment: @LieRyan That would be indeed a bit more secure, but there are still many other security issues (email delivery is very worse from a security standpoint), and CAs aren't actually doing it.

Answer (score 2):

So yes, if the operator of `www.dodgy-domain.elbonia` lists a WHOIS contact address of `admin@dodgy-domain.elbonia`, or if a CA can be convinced to send a verification e-mail to `postmaster@dodgy-domain.elbonia`, and that operator has not set up SSL support in e-mail yet or the CA doesn't have outgoing SSL support for e-mail, several parties could potentially intercept that e-mail, including the Corrupt Communications Ministry of Elbonia or someone with a tap on the party-line modem link out to the operator's site.

There's a chicken-and-egg problem too, because you can't receive STARTTLS-protected e-mail without a certificate on your mailserver.

However, that isn't necessarily a problem for the Internet as a whole, or for the majority of domains, or for a typical domain. Google, Yahoo!, Microsoft, `mail.com`, Apple all support STARTTLS, and a lot of newly established domains, personal domains, or small-business domains would have WHOIS addresses from one of those services rather than from the domain itself. Other organizations use Google Apps or hosted Exchange for their incoming mail, which means they get the same STARTTLS protection. Notably, `markmonitor.us`, which handles domain registration on behalf of a lot of Fortune 500 firms and other large organizations, uses Google Apps hence supports STARTTLS.

Also, a passive attacker (who could read the message but not block its delivery) would leave the "confirmation" e-mail in the target mailbox, which gives some risk that the real administrator will notice the e-mail, contact the CA, get the certificate cancelled, publicly warn his users, and report the matter to the police.

Note that at least one CA [does not issue](https://www.digicert.com/dv-ssl-certificate.htm) DV certificates in part because of concern for possible man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: I disagree with your attacker model. Advocating for `STARTTLS` as a solution here suggests a passive attacker (indeed, you mention potentially delivered emails as red flags), but when the traffic is passing through (or routed through) adversary-controlled infrastructure (such as Elbonia's ISP), I see no reason not to assume active capabilities. I'm not aware of any countermeasures against an active attacker between the CA and the server, and that's a scary thought.